# Is there a way to access my guesses_left variable from the TimeToGuess class for when I need to check if they run out of guesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am building a basic guessing game app in Kivy to learn the basics of it but don't quite fully understand it all yet. I need to access guesses_left when I go to the next screen(TimeToGuess) so that when I am writing the logic to remove guesses, if they guess wrong, and eventually lose if they run out.

I have already tried to set the TimeToGuess class attribute as Guesses in order to access it theat way but using canvas.clear() on the button release which also switches to TimeToGuess wasn't working for me.

here is the python file code:

```
from kivy import *
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

guesses_left = int()
computer_num = random.randint(1, 10)
user_guess = int()

class WannaPlay(Screen):
    pass


class Guesses(Screen):
    guesses_left = int()


class TimeToGuess(Screen):
        def user_is_guessing(self):
        if user_guess != computer_num:
            guesses_left -= 1


class Winner(Screen):
    pass


class Loser(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('guessinggame.kv')


class GuessingGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuessingGameApp().run()
```

and the .kv:

```
ScreenManage:
    WannaPlay:
    Guesses:
    TimeToGuess:
    Winner:
    Loser:


<WannaPlay>:
    name: 'start'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Want to Play the Guessing Game?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Button:
                name: 'yes'
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'

            Button:
                name: 'no'
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()


<Guesses>
    name: 'guess_choice'
    id: guesses_choice
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'How Many Guesses Would You Like?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_one'
                text: '1'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 1
                    print(guesses_left)



            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_two'
                text: '2'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 2
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_three'
                text: '3'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 3
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_four'
                text: '4'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 4
                    print(guesses_left)


<TimeToGuess>
    name: 'time_to_guess'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Guess a number between 1 and 10'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 5

            Button:
                name: 'guess_1'
                text: '1'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_2'
                text: '2'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_3'
                text: '3'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_4'
                text: '4'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_5'
                text: '5'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_6'
                text: '6'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_7'
                text: '7'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_8'
                text: '8'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_9'
                text: '9'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_10'
                text: '10'
```

Thanks in advance for the help

This is updated code to show how the checked answer did in fact help to resolve at least that problem(I'm sure I will have more issues to come though. lol)

Python code:

```
from kivy import *
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

guesses_left = int()
user_guess = int()
computer_num = random.randint(1, 10)


class WannaPlay(Screen):
    pass


class Guesses(Screen):
    pass


def user_is_guessing(guesses_amount=guesses_left, computer_num=computer_num):
    if user_guess != computer_num and guesses_amount == 0:
        #subtract from  guesses_left go to lose page
        pass
    elif guesses_amount == computer_num:
        #go to win page
        pass
    elif guesses_amount != computer_num:
        #subtract from guesses_left and have the user guess again
        pass


class TimeToGuess(Screen):
    pass


class Winner(Screen):
    pass


class Loser(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('guessinggame.kv')


class GuessingGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuessingGameApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
ScreenManage:
    WannaPlay:
    Guesses:
    TimeToGuess:
    Winner:
    Loser:


<WannaPlay>:
    name: 'start'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Want to Play the Guessing Game?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Button:
                name: 'yes'
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'

            Button:
                name: 'no'
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()


<Guesses>
    name: 'guess_choice'
    id: guesses_choice
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'How Many Guesses Would You Like?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_one'
                text: '1'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 1
                    print(guesses_left)



            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_two'
                text: '2'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 2
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_three'
                text: '3'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 3
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_four'
                text: '4'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 4
                    print(guesses_left)


<TimeToGuess>
    name: 'time_to_guess'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Guess a number between 1 and 10'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 5

            Button:
                name: 'guess_1'
                text: '1'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_2'
                text: '2'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_3'
                text: '3'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_4'
                text: '4'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_5'
                text: '5'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_6'
                text: '6'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_7'
                text: '7'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_8'
                text: '8'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_9'
                text: '9'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_10'
                text: '10'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't touched Kivy for a while, so I'm not completely sure this will work, but if obeys basic OOP then this should work.

You could just declare the guesses_left variable outside the specific class, making it accessible to all your classes. i.e:

```
from kivy import *
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Initilize here
guesses_left = int()

class WannaPlay(Screen):
    pass


class Guesses(Screen):
    # instead of here
    pass


class TimeToGuess(Screen):
    pass


class Winner(Screen):
    pass


class Loser(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('guessinggame.kv')


class GuessingGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Or initilize here
    # guesses_left = int()
    GuessingGameApp().run()
```

If that won't run, leave a comment and I'll look into it further when I can.

Comment: Ok, so that seemed to kind of work at first but now it won't let me call back to that variable within the function and that is where problems start to occur now. I have updated the code above to reflect this

Comment: Which "function" are you trying to call it from and what is the error message?

Comment: I actually think that I fixed my issue thanks to this issue and thanks to pycharm's little hints about what I should do. I greatly appreciate the help! I am going to add a comment to show what I currently have done

Answer (score 0):

This is updated code to show how the above answer did in fact help to resolve at least that problem(I'm sure I will have more issues to come though. lol)

Python code:

```
from kivy import *
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

guesses_left = int()
user_guess = int()
computer_num = random.randint(1, 10)


class WannaPlay(Screen):
    pass


class Guesses(Screen):
    pass


def user_is_guessing(guesses_amount=guesses_left, computer_num=computer_num):
    if user_guess != computer_num and guesses_amount == 0:
        #subtract from  guesses_left go to lose page
        pass
    elif guesses_amount == computer_num:
        #go to win page
        pass
    elif guesses_amount != computer_num:
        #subtract from guesses_left and have the user guess again
        pass


class TimeToGuess(Screen):
    pass


class Winner(Screen):
    pass


class Loser(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('guessinggame.kv')


class GuessingGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuessingGameApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
ScreenManage:
    WannaPlay:
    Guesses:
    TimeToGuess:
    Winner:
    Loser:


<WannaPlay>:
    name: 'start'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Want to Play the Guessing Game?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Button:
                name: 'yes'
                text: 'Yes'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'guess_choice'

            Button:
                name: 'no'
                text: 'No'
                on_release:
                    app.stop()


<Guesses>
    name: 'guess_choice'
    id: guesses_choice
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'How Many Guesses Would You Like?'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 4

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_one'
                text: '1'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 1
                    print(guesses_left)



            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_two'
                text: '2'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 2
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_three'
                text: '3'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 3
                    print(guesses_left)

            Button:
                name: 'guess_amount_four'
                text: '4'
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 0
                    root.manager.current = 'time_to_guess'
                    guesses_left = 4
                    print(guesses_left)


<TimeToGuess>
    name: 'time_to_guess'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: 'Guess a number between 1 and 10'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 5

            Button:
                name: 'guess_1'
                text: '1'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_2'
                text: '2'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_3'
                text: '3'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_4'
                text: '4'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_5'
                text: '5'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_6'
                text: '6'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_7'
                text: '7'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_8'
                text: '8'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_9'
                text: '9'
            Button:
                name: 'guess_10'
                text: '10'
```

Comment: You should probably add this to the bottom of your question as an edit to your question so it is easier for people to follow should they look later. Referencing things like "the above answer" will change with time, as different answer may come it, be upvoted, etc. You can reference my answer simply as the "marked answer" or the answer by @TopherBuckley. Cheers!

Comment: will do. Thank you!